# asp image-button, CSS padding removed when clicked

Tags: html, css, asp.net, padding, imagebutton

I have an ASP image button with an ASP LinkButton next to it. I gave the Linkbutton a padding of 1% to give it some space. It looks like this when at rest:

[image]

However when I click the image, the padding is removed so it looks like this:

[image]

The movement of the words is very obvious on the page, is there a property or anything I am missing to prevent this?

Relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="flex-container flex-align-center">
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="userNameHeaderLbl" CssClass="nonAnimatedLink allowPointer contentMargin" Text="Not Signed In" OnClick="profileBtn_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="headerProfileBtn" ImageUrl="/Resources/Icons/03-Profile.png" CssClass="allowPointer" OnClick="profileBtn_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</div>

.flex-container {   
    display: flexbox; 
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

}
.flex-align-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nonAnimatedLink {text-decoration:none; color:white;}
.nonAnimatedLink:hover {text-decoration:none}

.contentMargin {padding:1%;}
```

Comment: Have you checked with chrome dev tools that contentMargin class is still applied after postback

Comment: it is reapplied after after postback. However the page takes a second to load. So you notice the movement before the new view is updated. This section is in an update panel fyi.